# Unable to connect to Teradata from PHP WSock32 DLL

Tags: php, odbc, teradata

I'm trying to connect to a `Teradata` server using **PHP**, **PDO** and **ODBC**. Example code:

```
<?php

$username = "tuser";
$password = "tpassword";

$dbcName = "tdata";
$dsn = "odbc:Driver=Teradata;DBCName=$dbcname";

try{

    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, [

        PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 20,
    ]);

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    die($e);
}
```

But after executing the script, an error does appear

> [WSock32 DLL] HostUnreach: Teradata server can't currently be reached
>   over this network.

Ping to Teradata server and telnet with Teradata server is successful. How to connect to server properly?
I'm using a `Windows Server 2012` with `PHP 7`.

Comment: Check your gateway rules. See if you can telnet to the TD host first directly. Also, if you have an ODBC DSN, you can test it in the ODBC Manager itself.

Comment: @access_granted Thank you for your answer, telnet is work’s fine. Gateway is off. Connection test successfully. The problem was with OpenServer package, which is included PHP. OpenServer package in default mode using it’s own Path. I’am change option to own Path + Windows Path and connection become successful